Finder: force update of "locations" for USB memory stick
MacOS Ventura 13.6.6
lsusb returns
Bus 020 Device 008: ID 0781:XXXX SanDisk Corporation Cruzer Blade  Serial: 04014931
Is there a terminal command or other method to force Finder to add the USB device to Finder?

Use Disk Utility to confirm the volume is mounted.


In the Disk Utility app on your Mac, select the volume you want to mount.
Click the Mount button.


https://support.apple.com/guide/disk-utility/dskutl1027/22..6/mac/14.0
If already mounted, you can unmount and remount the volume, or

You can also make an external volume available by disconnecting the external device from your Mac, then reconnecting it.

https://support.apple.com/guide/disk-utility/dskutl1027/22..6/mac/14.0
